# How to set Width of DropDowList Items using Razor

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am not able to change the width of the items in a DropDownList.
I need that DropDown items has a size width different of DropDown.
Someone help me?

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @f.FormGroup().DropDownList("IdTipoAcao", new SelectList(this.ViewBag.TipoAcao, "IdTipoAcao", "Tipo", Model.IdTipoAcao > 0 ? Model.IdTipoAcao : 0)).Id("cmbTipoAcao").Label().LabelText("Tipo de Ação")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownList(
"ListId", 
variable, 
new { style = "width: 250px;" }
```

)

Comment: Thus the Dropdown stayed with the size 250px or 150px, what I need is that the items of DropDown have a size, and not the entire DropDown

Answer (score 0):

You should use css to set the width of html elements not razor. Assuming IdTipoAcao is the id of the drop down element.

```
#IdTipoAcao {
 width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Thus the Dropdown stayed with the size 250px or 150px, what I need is that the items of DropDown have a size, and not the entire DropDown